# Exception in ActivityThread.setupGraphicsSupport()

Tags: android

I got the exception message from user.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.setupGraphicsSupport(ActivityThread.java:3738)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3808)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

He uses samsung galaxy S2 (ICS 4.0.3 with tegrak kernel and ADW launcher ex)

It's difficult to find what's the problem with this exception log.

Can anybody suggest a starting point to find why this exception raised.

Thanks.

Comment: Can You show the code of the activity?